# AJAX content not loading into appended html

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

I am working on a portfolio project. I want to build a custom lightbox style script that loads content from another shared domain page into a newly created popup div using AJAX. A loading bar will appear while the content is being delivered.

**The Problem:**
The content is not loading into the popup window as it should. AJAX should be pulling the content of the `#single-project-wrapper` section from another page and loading it into the `#framebox-content` section that is appended to the home page body with jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var $ = jQuery;

    jQuery('.framebox-trigger').click(function(e){

        // Prevent default linking
        e.preventDefault();

                             // Add content for lightbox type display
        var $singleContent = '<div id="framebox-overlay">' +
                               '<section id="framebox-content">' +
                                  '<div class="framebox-close">' +
                                    '<p>Click to close</p>' +
                                  '</div>' +
                                  //AJAX to insert #single-project-wrapper content here
                                '</section>' +
                              '</div>',
                 $bodyCall = $('body'),
                   $toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #single-project-wrapper';


    // Add overlay and loading bar
    $bodyCall.removeClass('framebox-freeze');
    $bodyCall.addClass('framebox-freeze').append($singleContent, loadContent);
    // Add loading beacon
    $('.framebox-freeze').append('<span id="framebox-loading">+ Loading +</span>');
    $('#framebox-loading, #framebox-overlay').fadeIn('fast');

    // Load AJAX content
    function loadContent(){
        $('#framebox-content').load($toLoad , showNewContent)
    };

    // Show loaded AJAX content and hide loading bar
    function showNewContent(){
        $('#single-project-wrapper').show('normal', hideLoader)
    };

    // Hide loading bar
    function hideLoader(){
        $('#framebox-loading').fadeOut('fast')
    };

    });

    // Close out Framebox
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#framebox-overlay, #framebox-close', function(){
        $bodyCall.removeClass('framebox-freeze');
        $('#framebox-overlay, #framebox-loading').fadeOut('fast');
  });

});
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong!!

**Other things that could be important to know:**

- This is running on a wordpress site
- At this point the site is only running locally through MAMP

If anyone can help me out, it would be much appreciated. I'm new to jQuery and trying to learn, and this is a mashup of several tutorials. Sorry if it's a mess. Let me know if you need anything else.

## EDIT/UPDATE!!!!!

As said below by @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ, I was using `.append` all wrong. Changing this line:

```
$bodyCall.addClass('framebox-freeze').append($singleContent, loadContent);
```

to this works:

```
$bodyCall.addClass('framebox-freeze').append($singleContent).fadeIn('fast', loadContent);
```

This solves the issue of getting the content.

**Now, however,** the content loads as it should on the first link selection, but then on subsequent selections, the loading bar does not disappear, and floats over the loaded content. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) doesn't have a `(content,function)` ie. `.append($singleContent, loadContent)` - just `(content,content)` and  `(function())`

Comment: YES!!! I must have missed that somehow!

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward it fixed the loading issue, but now I am having an issue with content not loading in the proper order after the first click.

Answer (score 0):

In your function loadContent() you need to put a $ sign before 'toLoad' since this is a jquery variable which you made earlier on.

Comment: You are correct, however that didn't change anything! ( I editted the post to include it now). Thanks!